# Usage et prononciation de « cote », « coté », « côte » et « côté »

Tags: sens, prononciation

Dans quelles situations peut-on emploie les mots en question ? Prononce-on les quatre mots de la même manière ?

Peut-on remplacer *au côté* par *du côte* dans les cas suivants ?

> *Au* côté exigence, on est des vrais cochons.
>
> *Du* côté exigence, on est des vrais cochons.

Quelles sont les règles d'utilisation (*au* ou *du*) ?

S'il y a aussi des astuces en anglais pour mieux comprendre, je veux bien les connaître.

Comment: Écouter la prononciation sur Shtooka [cote](http://shtooka.net/search.php?str=cote&lang=fra), [coté](http://shtooka.net/search.php?str=cot%C3%A9&lang=fra), [côte](http://shtooka.net/search.php?str=c%C3%B4te&lang=fra), [côté](http://shtooka.net/search.php?str=c%C3%B4t%C3%A9&lang=fra).

Comment: Il y a plusieurs fautes dans la phrase « Est-ce que ma dernier phrase vous paraisse bonne ? » On dit « dernière phrase » car phrase est un mot féminin. Et l'usage du subjonctif n'est pas correct ici, donc « paraît bonne » et non « paraisse bonne ».

Comment: @Laure@Lamine Merci.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les quatre mots cités sont :

> **1**: **cote** : (*quotation/rating*)  La **cote** du thon rouge s'effondre sur le marché de Tokyo.
>
> **2**: **coté** : (*quoted/rated*) Ce 4x4 n'est plus **coté** à l'Argus.
>
> **3**: **côte** : (*coast*)  La **Côte**-d'Azur
>
> **4**: **côté** : (*side*)   Du **côté** droit.

**cote** et **côte** se prononcent différemment, le premier avec un **o** ouvert et le deuxième avec un **o** fermé. Cependant, la tendance est à la perte de cette distinction et des variations régionales existent, par exemple dans le sud de la France où ils ne se distinguent en général pas.

**coté** et **côté** se prononcent le plus souvent de manière identique, mais certains font encore la distinction, comme au Québec.

Les phrases « *<s>Au</s> côté exigence, on est des vrais cochons.* » et « *<s>Du</s> côté exigence, on est des vrais cochons.* » sont incorrectes. On pourrait dire :

> *Côté exigence, on est des vrais cochons* (ou *nous sommes de vrais cochons*)

ou

> *Du côté des exigences, on est* ...

Comment: J’ajouterais « Du côté de l’exigence, […] », qui me semble moins familier que « Côté exigence ». De plus, son « filez » est ici clairement un pluriel et non un vouvoiement.

Comment: @Édouard merci, j'ai retiré le point sur le vouvoiement clairement incorrect en effet.

Comment: *2 et 4 se prononcent de manière identique* est ambigu. Il vaudrait mieux associer 2 à 1 et 4 à 3.

Comment: @M42 J'ai modifié ma réponse cependant je ne vois pas en quoi cette phrase était ambiguë.

Comment: Parce qu'on a l'impression que tu dis que `coté` et `côté` se prononcent de la même façon.

Comment: Est-ce que la phrase reste identique si on pousse *Côté exigence* à la fin ?

Comment: @M42, tel que je le prononce, 1, 2 et 4 ont un o ouvert et 3 un o fermé. Je prononce donc bien 2 et 4 de la même manière.

Comment: Je trouve un peu irritant de parler de prononciation. Ici (au Québec), **côté** et **coté** ne se prononcent pas de la même manière. Il faudrait donc expliciter la région où cette situation se produit.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: cote -> [kɔt], coté ->  [kɔte], côte -> [kot], côté -> [kote]. coté et côté ne se prononcent pas du tout de la même façon.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, je doute qu'il faille aller jusqu'au Québec pour entendre des différences.  Je connais des gens qui n'en font jamais entre [o] et [ɔ] et d'autres qui la font différemment de moi pour certains mots (_rose_ dont le o est fermé pour moi est un exemple courant).

Comment: @M42, c'était bien ce que je disais sans ambiguïté mais de façon erronée.

Comment: Erronée, c'est à voir. La note du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c%C3%B4te) sur la prononciation contient "Il y a en fait hésitation entre [o] fermé et [ɔ] ouvert pour côté, côtelé, côtelette ainsi que le soulignent Grammont Prononc. 1958 et Fouché Prononc. 1959, p. 80. Pour Grammont la prononc. avec [o] fermé qu'on entend le plus souvent est due à l'influence de l'accent circonflexe mais la prononc. la plus spontanée est celle avec [ɔ]. Il en donne pour preuve qu'il n'y a aucune hésitation dans coteau écrit sans accent circonflexe, toujours prononcé avec [ɔ]."

Comment: @Unfrancophone c'est pour ça que je suggérais d'ajouter des précisions sur la prononciation; mais bon, poser des questions sur la prononciation semble faire office de troll car personne ne s'entendra jamais :P

Comment: "Tu as le cote" -- c'est lie au deuxieme sens ci-dessous, non ?

Comment: @Drew « le cote » est incorrect. « Tu as la cote. » utilise le premier mot.

Comment: @jlliagre -- oups.  Bien sur : "la", et le premier sens ci-dessus. Merci.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Sans parler de troll, les prononciations sont souvent régionales et peuvent varier grandement. J'avais ce débat récemment avec des collègues qui ne font pas de distinction phonétique entre « j'allais » et « j'allai » là où j'en fais une (/jalè/ vs /jalé/). Il est donc difficile de donner une réponse absolue à moins de pouvoir dire clairement dans quelles régions tel mot est prononcé de telle façon. Si tu as des statistiques de ce genre, c'est toutefois intéressant. La réponse de jlliagre correspond aux cas que je rencontre habituellement en Lorraine.